# How to display Response message as Response code is coming in jmeter

Tags: jmeter

As i am new in jmeter there when i run the code for all the http request  Response code is showing but Response message is not display its display blank

My protocol [http]: is https

my  http request is 
[image]

advance section is

[image]

sampler result

[image]

Answer (score 2):

JMeter normally displays HTTP status message so if you i.e. open http://example.com website using [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler you will see the status message `OK` in the [View Results Tree](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener.

[image]

If you're not seeing the relevant message in JMeter it means that your application doesn't return it, you can double check it using a sniffer tool like [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/) or [Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler) and raise an issue in your application bug tracking system in order to get this fixed.

If the absence of the `OK` status message prevents you from continuing working on your script for some reason you can manually amend the status message using [JSR223 PostProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor)

1. Add JSR223 PostProcessor as a child of the request which response message you want to modify
2. Put the following code into "Script" area:

   ```
   if (prev.getResponseCode().equals('200')) {
       prev.setResponseMessageOK()
   }
   ```

   In the above code `prev` stands for [HTTPSampleResult](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/protocol/http/sampler/HTTPSampleResult.html) class instance, check out JavaDoc for comprehensive information about methods/fields and [Top 8 JMeter Java Classes You Should Be Using with Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/top-8-jmeter-java-classes-you-should-be-using-with-groovy/) guide to learn more about JMeter API shortcuts available for JSR223 Test Elements
3. That's it, if you get [HTTP Status 200](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/200) from the server the response message will be set to `OK`